# Linker errors when compiling disksim4 with 64-bit extensions

Tags: c, simulator

I'm trying to compile the Disksim4 simulator with dixtrac. I've followed the instructions from here: http://cighao.com/2016/03/23/disksim-with-ssdmodel-source-analysis-013-use-it-on-64bit/ to install the SSD patch along with the 2 patches recommended on that page.

All the required files compile (however with many warnings about implicit function declarations). However, it fails at the following command:

```
gcc -Wall -Wno-unused -MD -I. -I../diskmodel/include -I../libparam/include -I../libddbg/include -g -DASSERTS   -I../memsmodel/include -I../ssdmodel/include -D_INLINE  -o disksim disksim_main.o -L. -ldisksim -L../diskmodel/lib -ldiskmodel -L../memsmodel/lib -lmemsmodel -L../ssdmodel/lib -lssdmodel -L../libparam/lib -lparam -L../libddbg/lib -lddbg -lm
```

For example,

```
./libdisksim.a(disksim.o): In function `addlisttoextraq': /home/karthik/school/disksim-4.0/src/disksim.c:235: undefined reference to `addtoextraq'
```

All the errors are similar to the one above. Not sure how to proceed to fix this. If anyone is familiar with this and has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it! thank you!

Comment: Any reason why you can't add all files to your favourite IDE and have it handle the compilation and linking?

Comment: @LundinI was just trying to get it to work 'as is' without having to move files and essentially create my own project. But if nothing else works, I might have to do that!Thanks

Comment: It's the least painful way. Single command line or make files is a thing of the past, better to focus on actual programming.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from the higher version of GCC. I've seen this error too when I try to `make` in the `disksim-4.0` directory using GCC-10 and GCC-9. After searching a lot of information, finally I found that it is the version of GCC that causes this error.

Switch to a lower version of GCC (I switched to GCC-4.9), then just `make` in the `disksim-4.0` directory as above. Now you can successfully compile disksim-4.0!

If you do not know how to install a lower version of GCC, here is the link: [Install lower version of GCC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235819/ubuntu-20-04-gcc-version-lower-than-gcc-7).

Also, here is the link that tells you how to install multiple versions of GCC in your Linux and the way to switch between them:[How to switch between multiple GCC and G++ compiler versions on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-switch-between-multiple-gcc-and-g-compiler-versions-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa).

FYI.